# How can you create a post-installation landing page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that contains all of its functionality in a Browser Action. Meaning that the user has to click the icon in the upper right to open the main menu that everything is accesible through.

I have found that many people after installing the extension do not realize the addition of the icon in the upper right and I would like to add a landing page that automatically loads after installing the extension. This page would have getting started help information, including an arrow or something showing them where the new icon is so they know how to access the extension.

I know how to programmatically add a new tab or window and load a certain page but my main question is how to detect when the user has just finished installing the chrome extension. Is there something Google provides to do this already? I think many other extensions already do it.

I considered using local storage to add a "messageDisplayed" variable and if that is not set launch it from the background script, but I'm afraid if the extension syncs to another browser it might pop up randomly anytime they use chrome on a new computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `localStorage`. There will be some minor collateral damage for people with multiple browsers but they generally will be more advanced users who will be more understanding. There is an e[xperimental storage sync API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.storage.html) that will hopefully land in the next stable release. Once it goes live you can use it to sync to other computers that the intro page has already been displayed.